# Why the value of kw is different？

Tags: python

I wrote a function to handle coroutine exceptions and interrupts,logfunc is used to record the progress of the task before interruption.code show as below

```py
def async_process(task,logfunc=None,**kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        # loop.set_debug(True)

        return loop.run_until_complete(task(**kwargs))
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    finally:
        try:
            all_tasks = asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks(loop), return_exceptions=True)
            all_tasks.cancel()
            with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(all_tasks)
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        finally:
            # save_last_id(last_id, **kwargs)
            logfunc
            loop.close()
```

But when I call like this

```py
for kw in rules_options:
            async_process(key_processing, logfunc=save_last_id(last_id, kw, 'webinfo'), load_id=load_id(kw,'webinfo'), kw=kw)
```

The value of kw passed in save_last_id is not the same as the value of kw passed in key_processing?
Why?

#### Additional：

About variable rules_options

```py
configer.read("rule.txt")
rules_options = configer.options("rules")
```

The content in my "rule.txt" like this:

```py
[rules]
catg=key1,key2,key3
```

About save_last_id function  and load_id

```py
def save_last_id(id,kw,table_name):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('log.db', check_same_thread=False)
    configer = configparser.ConfigParser()
    configer.read(config)
    rule = configer.get("rules", kw)

    if id != "-1" or id is not None :
        connection.execute("insert or replace into {} (key,rule,last_id) values ('{}','{}','{}')".format(table_name, kw, rule, id))
        connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def load_id(kw,table_name):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('log.db', check_same_thread=False)
    connection.executescript("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(
                key TEXT NOT NULL,
                rule TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                last_id TEXT
            )
            """.format(table_name)
                            )
    try:
        configer = configparser.ConfigParser()
        configer.read(config)
        rule = configer.get("rules", kw)
        print("select last_id from {} where rule = '{}' ".format(table_name, rule))
        last_id = connection.execute("select last_id from {} where rule = '{}' ".format(table_name, rule)).fetchone()

        if last_id is None:
            return -1
        elif len(last_id) == 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return last_id[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return -1
```

Comment: This could happen if either `save_last_id` or `load_id` changed `kw`,  I don't know what type of object `kw` is and I don't know what those functions do, so I don't know if that is what is going on.  In any case, I think the answer is likely to be in some code you didn't post.  It would help if you could construct and post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the question.function key_processing is just a function for kw processing, print can also be used instead

Comment: I don't see any obvious explanation for what you have observed in what you posted.  It is far from minimal.  If you relentlessly simplify it, you will either find the problem or get a small demonstration that someone else can analyze.